# Avoid using bundle name in template names

Tags: templates, symfony, bundle

I am getting frustrated with the amount of code i write just to include templates and am wondering if there's a way to include a template from a controller or a template in the same bundle without writing the bundle name?

so instead of this:

```
$this->render('AcmeBlogBundle:Controller:template.html.php');
```

I would be able to write just this:

```
$this->render('::template.html.php')
```

It is repeating code and it's a shame.

Comment: `::template.html.php` already refers the template `app/Resources/views/template.html.php`, thus you can't use it. However, this notation is currently not implemented (anymore/yet) because of security issues: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/#embedding-controllers

Comment: Take a look at the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle and its `@Template` annotation, it will help you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html